# Como solucionar error de backup sql server: No se puede abrir el archivo de copia de saguridad?

Tags: c#, sql

alguien sabe como se soluciona este error?
Lo tengo cuando desde mi sistema intento crear un backup, lo estoy teniendo hasta hoy que he generado el ejecutable o instalador, lo que me parece un poco raro porque hasta ahora me da este error, cabe destacar que la base de datos esta en un servidor remoto, pero alcanzable y ya esta mapeado en mi PC, pero no me deja crear el backup, mencionar tambien que lo intento crear tanto en una carpeta del servidor y en una de mi compitadora pero de igual manera no funciona y muestra errores como este, ademas navegando por diferentes preguntas parecidas en esta plataforma lei que tenia que ver con los permisos de windows, le di todos los permisos posibles a la carpeta y aun asi no me deja crear el backup, el codigo del procedimiento almacenado que se intenta ejecutar es este:

```
backup database ServiDB to disk =@nombre with init,stats=10
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podria estar ocurriendo? en mi maquina ya le otorgue todos los permisos a todos los usuarios y aun asi no me genera el backup....

Comment: ¿Existe esa computadora? ¿Puedes encontrarla por la red?

Comment: El Agente de SQLServer tiene permisos de escritura a la carpeta? La carpeta existe?

Comment: Hola si la caomputadora si existe y eso, pero lo de que si el agente tiene pemisos no se, de hecho me pondre a ver eso a detalle y les cuento, solo que no se si me agarrrara el sa de mi maquina o el del servidor eso estara algo raro

Comment: ahorita cambie la conexion string de el sistema y pues desde mi maquina hacia mis carpetas no hay ningun problema, el problema es cuando a el servidor, desde el servidor remotamente no puedo generar el backup

Comment: Acabo de alla la solucion mas pedorra pero funciona, lo que hago es ponerr \\myIp\carpeta\nombreBackup y solo asi me funciona la babosada esa y literalmente debo poner la ip porque si pongo el nombre de mi maquina no funciona

Comment: @Arriel eso es lo mas que logre